# D3.js Collapsible Tree nodes from mysql data on click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, d3.js

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

i am preparing a model in ASP.NET based on the above link
how to get each node from mysql database using on click example flare would be the parent when i click flare it should go to the database and fetch record from database and it should display as analytics, animate, data, display flex and so on.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: if user type flare in the text box it should get records from DB only the first set of data should show example "analytic", "animate", "data", "display". from that if user click analytic if should go to DB and fetch records for analytic the records are " cluster" , " Graph" and "Optimization" should show followed

Comment: That's not a question, that's a statement. Do you want us to implement this for you?

Comment: Is there any links to refer ? or if possible a sample

Comment: There are no examples for this exact case as far as I know.

Comment: if possible i need a sample from your side ?